# How can I validate year using date API in java

Tags: java

I wrote some code which is validating date, but why is it not validate year?
see **1234** is not valid year even it gives no error.

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        df.setLenient(false);
        Date date=df.parse("10/4/1234");
        System.out.println("date------->"+date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Error in sql server Procedure:**

> SELECT @CONVERT_DATETIME = convert(datetime, @DB_DATE, 103);
>
> SET @STORE_DB = CAST(((CAST(DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01',ltrim(rtrim(@CONVERT_DATETIME))) as bigint))  * 1000 - @GMT5) as varchar(MAX));

Comment: Why you think that 1234 is not valid year?

Comment: [1234 *is* a valid year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1234).

Comment: Are you saying that there was no year 1234? +1 @ChrisMantle-didn't know there are wiki articles on years ;)

Comment: I have some date entries year like 99, 3456,20122 through user input. so I think user can done such kind of mistake. so I want to validate date.

Comment: I think he missed out some minus sign during the post

Comment: now I have such requirement to convert date into long and migrate data. so I created procedure in SQL Server. but it throws exception and unable to convert it.

Comment: I want to validate user date input but if it is not possible then why sql server give error while conversion such date into long.

Answer (score 3):

1234 is of course a valid year.

If you want more restrictions, you can use a GregorianCalendar to validate the year.
For instance:

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(myDate);
if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) < 1970) {
    throw new ParseException("Date under 1970 are not allowed!", 6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned 1234 is a valid year. I am assuming you want a way to identify 1234 as not the correct year that needs to be used.

You can extract the year from the String and do a simple comparison.

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(df.parse("10/4/1234"));

        System.out.println("Year = " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        // check the condition whether year is valid
        if( c.get(Calendar.YEAR) < 1970 ) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Year entered");
            // you can throw an exception here if you want
        }
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can use the Calendar API to extract day, month, minutes, second etc.

In your example ParseException will occur if you used

```
the date "10/4/12345"
```

for the following format

```
SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

because 12345 does not match "yyyy"